# Why would a method work successfully in VBA even though it's not listed in the object library under the specific class?

Tags: vba, interface, com

In VBA I have the Microsoft HTML add in referenced.  I'm declaring a variable as an IHTMLelement object.  From there, I can still use the .getelementsbyclassname method without getting a syntax error despite the fact that this is not listed under the possible methods for the IHTMLelement class.  There are several other variables for which this is an acceptable method, but I don't understand why it would work for this one

```
Sub overflowquestion()

'Turn on References to Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML 

'Object Library before running

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, el As IHTMLElement, sl As IHTMLElement

IE.navigate "www.youtube.com"

Do While IE.readyState <> 4

    DoEvents

Loop

Set el = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("skip-nav")(0)

'Why does this next line work?

Set sl = el.getElementsByClassName("masthead-search-terms-border")(0)


End Sub
```

Comment: I think I should have asked a more generic question about the object library.  Now that I'm looking at it there are a lot of classes that don't have methods listed, including the IHTMLdocument itself..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a number of things to understand here.

`el` is not an instance of an interface `IHTMLElement` it is an instance of a class Element which implements the `IHTMLElement` interface.  Classes can implement multiple interfaces. The `Element` class may have inherited from another class, and it may implement several other interfaces, one of these classes/interfaces has the method getElementsByClassName

As noted by Paulo Madeira in the comments,  VBA is capable of late binding (see the docs for an [overview of Interfaces, Classes, late an early binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260635(v=vs.60).aspx)) so it will try calling the method on the object whether the interface says it can or not.

Comment: Interesting.  While I can tell this is the correct answer to my question a lot of it is lost in translation for me since I'm not very advanced.  For instance, how did you figure out that IHTMLelement is an instance of class Element? Is there a reference somewhere?  Is the element class akin to a collection in VBA (ex: Sheets collection encompasses both Worksheets and Chart sheets)?

Comment: There is a huge amount of information involved in explaining Interfaces vs Classes.  Basically an interface defines what methods a class will have whereas a class actually implements them.  you never have an instance of an interface, but you have an instance of a class that implements 1 or more interfaces.  This might help if you are up for some reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260635(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: It's not because VBA is interpreted (it's actually compiled to some sort of bytecode), it's because it's capable of late-bound invocation (namely, transforming an apparent unknown method call or property access into `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames` and `IDispatch::Invoke`), and because `IHTMLElement` doesn't have the [`[nonextensible]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367120(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute.  So, in fact, the `IDispatch`-based interface doesn't say it cannot be used for other methods.